# While loops is not looping indefinitely (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm writing a c++ code. My initial code is about accessing menu options via a console application but it seems that my whole loops is not working in my code. I want it to work indefinitely so that I can choose menu options as much as I want until I press 0. Any help ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    int temperature[] = { 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 20, 21, 25, 22, 17, 13, 10 };
    string months[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
    int x = 1;

    while (x != 0) {
        cout << "Choose an option from below: " << endl
             << endl;
        cout << "[1] "
             << "Temp of a month (name selection)" << endl;
        cout << "[2] "
             << "Temp of a month (number selection)" << endl;
        cout << "[3] "
             << "Calculate avg temperature" << endl;
        cout << "[4] "
             << "Hottest month" << endl;
        cout << "[5] "
             << "Sort the months" << endl;
        cout << "[0] "
             << "Terminate program" << endl;
        cin >> x;

        switch (x) {
        case 1: {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Choose the month: ";
            string m;
            cin >> m;
            for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
                if (m == months[i]) {
                    cout << "The Temperature of " << months[i] << " is " << temperature[i] << endl;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case 2: {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Choose the number of the month: ";
            int t;
            cin >> t;
            cout << temperature[t - 1] << endl;
            break;
        }

        case 0: {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Good bye user!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i=0;i>=0;i++)` this seems to be the bug.

Comment: *my whole loops is not working in my code* This is not a problem description. The program does exactly what you programmed and we don't know what you expected.

Comment: @IlCapitano Yes you are right my for loop condition was bugged, thank you